# Facebook integration for ios 5 & ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I want to integrate Facebook both for ios 5 and ios 6.

I have the knowledge of integrating facebook in individual ios(i.e ios 5 or ios 6), but have no idea of how to support facebook for both ios 5 and ios 6.

In the other words, how to integrate facebook both for ios 5 and ios 6 ? or what is the common way to support this in both ios?

Thanks

Comment: You can use share kit for both ios 5 & 6...

Comment: Facebook is integrated in ios 6 itself, for ios 5 you need to import the framework sdk.

Comment: @AppleDatasource, yes, My app support both  ios5 & ios6. So,how can i integrate facebook for both ios commonly.

Comment: you can not integrate Facebook in iOS 6 because it's uses it's native framework you can check the condition of os and set according functionality

Comment: Easy way to integrate facebook in IOS 6 http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/

Comment: Seriously how is this not a real question? It's not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, and can be answered...

Comment: When saying "integrating" Facebook, you are talking about the social graph API or are you intending to simply allow users to post?

Comment: here your solution

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467558/integrating-facebook-sdk-for-older-versions-of-xcode-to-support-both-ios-5-and-i/15471713#15471713

Comment: your solution is here


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467558/integrating-facebook-sdk-for-older-versions-of-xcode-to-support-both-ios-5-and-i/15471713#15471713

it helps u  !!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well if you want to use the facebook integration within iOS6, and if the iOS version is lower than 6 , you want to use the Facebook SDK for iOS, you can check for the availability of the integrated Facebook service class in the `Social Framework`. Also you would have to import the `Social Framework` for it.

```
#import<Social/Social.h>
```

You can check for the availability of the integrated facebook service by something like this in the `buttonAction` method

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    //Check for availability of Facebook integration and use its view controller to share on Facebook
    if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil) {
        SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
            //Use fbController for sharing
        } else {
            // Service not available
        }
    }
    else{
        // Use your code for sharing on iOS versions other than 6.x to authenticate and get an access token.
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: but in ios5, the the social framework is not there, so i am getting error like social.h not found

Comment: Make your `Social Framework` as an optional framework. Dont make it a required framework. It wont be required then for iOS < 6

Comment: Yes it will. Just do remember to make it optional. And properly implement the Facebook SDK for iOS versions < 6. Do go through their documentations.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this links for [ios 5](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/) and [ios 6](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/25/facebook-sdk-for-ios-and-the-ios-6-facebook-integration/).

Use the latest sdk for both ios 5 and 6, and follow the [link](https://parse.com/questions/ios-5-support-for-new-sdk) for details.

check this also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735962/supporting-both-ios-5-and-ios-6-with-the-facebook-sdk-3-1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have xcode 4.5 or later. Using social framework,you can implement Facebook on iOS. Also check FB and Twitter integration for iPhone tutorial.Visit http://kmithi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/integrating-facebook-and-twitter-in-ios.html