# Can't send data from application to twiiter using default twitter in iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter

i have used Twitter framework to send tweet.I want to pass some data from application to tweeter but it can't.

My code.
`

```
        if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {

        // Initialize Tweet Compose View Controller
        TWTweetComposeViewController *vc = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        UITextField *txtFild1=[[UITextField alloc]init];
        txtFild1.text=shareString;
        // Settin The Initial Text
        [vc setInitialText:self.shareString];
        [txtFild1 release];
        // Adding an Image

        // Adding a URL

        // Setting a Completing Handler
        [vc setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];

        // Display Tweet Compose View Controller Modally
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`

my data is in share string. but it don't set as initial text.

How can it solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add `Twitter.framework` from `Build Phases => LinkBinary with Libraries` and then import this file in your `.m` file like bellow...

```
#import <Twitter/TWTweetComposeViewController.h>
```

and then use this like bellow.. This is just an example..

```
- (IBAction)CallTwitter
{   
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [twitter setInitialText:@"Write Some Text Here"];


    [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];

    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {

        if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
        {

            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your Tweet was posted succesfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];



        }else if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {

            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Canceled" message:@"Your Tweet was not posted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
}
```

Comment: First NSLog this(means print that string) string .. see this isnot nil or empty.. check now..

Comment: @jinal use this line [twitter setInitialText:self.shareString];

Comment: which string(text,data) you want to display on initial text??

Comment: but which type of dynamic data you want to display?? means if here string is @"" then some other data is display like if string is @"" the text display 'Title' text right??

Comment: if i write in setIntial text like  this @"Hello!!" then it dissplay in twitter box of iphone.But i have data in sharestring from table view so i directly pass that string.But data of that string is not shown in twitter box.and sharestring have data.

Comment: are you sure you have a data?? in sharestring?? just properly just property-syantesize that string and retain it and then use it i am sure it will work.. i give another answer to someone before a minute for property-synthesize the string from this link see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196708/change-a-uilabels-text-from-another-class/14196872#14196708

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *shareString; and when i have write NSLog(@"%@",self.sharestring).i get data @"This business directory is shared to you via....".in TWTwittercomposer code given by you.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/ i try to link twitter another way in my app.But tweet not post in twitter.

Comment: here its limited string allowed to tweet on tweeter but here you get the output from this code???

Comment: if i write like this  [twitter setInitialText:@"Write Some Text Here"]; then it show but when write  [twitter setInitialText:self.sharestring];then no data display of sharestring.

Comment: i know why its happen , bcoz here character limit of Initial text is 140, if you want to set text then here you must enter < 140 character..

Comment: @jinal see this link for more information about it... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter

Comment: @jinal you got it now?? whats the problem here.. just substring your string with only 135 character and set as a initialText..

Comment: always wel-come dear.. also you can just take 135 character from string and post it on it with substringFromIndex method of NSString.. and if this answer helpful then accept the answer and also another answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196708/change-a-uilabels-text-from-another-class/14196872#14196708 link of your que.. increase your rate dear.. Thank you... :)

Comment: @jinal oh sorry dear on this link i give you answer its helpful ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136786/cant-dial-call-from-programatically-in-iphone if helpful then also accept that answer dear..

Comment: i want to use facebook from iphone  by default like twitter.But this available only in ios6.0.If want to use in ios5.0 then?

Comment: now you got it?? see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735962/supporting-both-ios-5-and-ios-6-with-the-facebook-sdk-3-1 .. now you got it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252311/facebook-integration-in-iphone-with-facebook-sdk-for-ios5-and-6/14252595#14252595  can you give answer for this?

Comment: then that not work but for that use sharekit or any other sdk for facebook just see my this answer for some sdk of facebook but use sharkit for that just take links from comment also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214903/facebook-sdk-changes-to-login-in-pop-up-view/14215393#comment19817219_14215393

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376759/apply-bezier-path-to-image-instead-of-imageview can you give answer of it?