# Change a UILabel's text from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I have a view controller and a class (I am using storyboards). How can I change the text of a  `UILabel` (in the view controller) from the class? I have tried this, but to no avail:

```
ViewController *mainView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[mainView view];

[mainView.progressBar setProgress:integer animated:YES];

NSLog(@"Updated Progress Bar");

NSString *progressLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ out of %i followers", userString, [self.followers count]];

[mainView.progressLabel setText:progressLabelText];

NSLog(@"Updated Progress Label Text: %@", progressLabelText);
```

The text does not change using this code. What should I be doing instead?

Edit: The progressbar and label in the ViewController's .h file look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *progressLabel;
```

And they are fully linked up in Interface Builder.

Comment: You should tell us more about the `ViewController` class. Is `progressLabel` an `IBOutlet`? If so, you're just alloc/init-ing the instance here, which will not load a xib, and therefore the outlet will never get plugged in.

Comment: Check for the Connections of the `progressBar` and `progressLabel`are properly made.

Comment: I think problem is related to your ViewController object. Here you have created new instance of ViewController. Is that the same object from which you are showing your view on screen?

Answer (score 3):

Use `delegate` for `messaging` between `classes` or `viewcontrollers`.

Refer [The Basics of Protocols and Delegates](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) link.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Notification for updating the Lable text.

in your viewController write this:

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) name:@"lblUpdate" object:nil];


  and selector is :
   -(void)updateLabel
{
    self.lblObject.text = @"Your updated text"
}
```

and now in your Class call this using Post notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"lblUpdate" object:nil];
```

remember use same notification name "lblUpdate"

Comment: Can anyone tell if that's the recommended way of doing it? It looks too simple to be something official lol Works perfectly tho, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

But use a `delegate` to do the callbacks.
In your `spamchecker.h` add:

```
@protocol SpamCheckerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)updateText:(NSString*)newText;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SpamCheckerDelegate> delegate;
```

In your `spamchecker.m` where you need it add:

```
[self.delegate updateText:@"newText"];
```

Then in your `mainView.h` add:

```
@interface MainView : UIViewController <SpamCheckerDelegate>
```

In your `mainview.m` add:

```
spamchecker.delegate = self;
```

And implement the method like:

```
-(void)updateText:(NSString*)newText
{
    [self.progressLabel setText:progressLabelText];
}
```

Comment: I have changed this accordingly. The label's text, however, still won't update.

Comment: The code looks fine. Maybe it has something to do with how you are allocating progressLabel. Does the progressbar update correctly?

Comment: The progressbar doesn't update either. I am using Storyboards if that makes any difference? (I'm new to them)

Comment: Yes, they are and they update perfectly if [self.progressLabel setText:@"Test"]; is called from the view controller rather than the class

Comment: Updated my asnwer. This should work, but I still don't know why setting it directly doesn't work

Comment: Does the method get called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22320/discussion-between-roland-keesom-and-pixelbit-apps-ltd)

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately :( the method isn't even called

Comment: How is SpamChecker allocated? And when setting its delegate?

Comment: This is in the VC's .h file: http://pixelbit.in/Lzxr. This is where I set the delegate in the VC's .m file: http://pixelbit.in/M0cE. This is the method in VC's .m file. This is where I make the call to the delegate from TSCSpamChecker: http://pixelbit.in/LzwD. And finally, this is TSCSpamChecker's .h file where I declare the delegate: http://pixelbit.in/LzwQ. I think I've done everything you said to do but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you give some more information about how spamChecker is created, and in what method?

Comment: spamChecker's delegate is set in viewDidLoad of the view controller - http://pixelbit.in/M00R. And this is in the .h file: http://pixelbit.in/M0qT. That is all, apart from the other screenshots I have sent you. There is no more spamChecker-related code.

Comment: But where is it created? Like TSCSpamchecker *spamChecker = [TSCSpamChecker alloc]init]; or is it a singleton class?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea why it shouldn't work. I would have to see more of the code to be able to help. Maybe you can investigate if the delegate is set and if it works.

Answer (score 0):

just property synthesize the string and then set that string in `viewWillAppear:` method of `ViewController.m` class

just take `NSString` variable in `ViewController.h` file like bellow..

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *progressText;
```

and  `synthesize` this in `ViewController.m` file like bellow..

```
@synthesize progressText;
```

after that in `viewDidLoad:` method just set text at starting to the `progressLableText` like bellow...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

     progressText = @"Your Text";
     [progressLabel setText:progressText];

}
```

and also in `viewWillAppear:` set the text like above...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [progressLabel setText:progressText];
}
```

and in your code just change something like bellow..

```
ViewController *mainView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[mainView view];

[mainView.progressBar setProgress:integer animated:YES];

NSLog(@"Updated Progress Bar");

NSString *progressLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ out of %i followers", userString, [self.followers count]];

mainView.progressText = progressLabelText;
[mainView.progressText retain];


NSLog(@"Updated Progress Label Text: %@", progressLabelText);
```

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: you push to another view from viewController??